# C#.NET MAUI - launch function in the separate process

Tags: c#, process, maui

Who knows how to do it? As I know, it is not possible with standard tools of .NET?

I try [this library](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.ExecFunction), and when I try to execute the following code:

```
Process executor;
...
executor = ExecFunction.Start(() => Environment.Exit(0));
```

=> the app starts to launch itself in the infinite loop and not to exit, that can be aborted only either by `taskkill` or by pressing and holding power. Who knows how to launch that code in a proper way? There are very old questions on StackOverflow that discuss this topic but I'd like to get the answer regarding the modern reality.

Comment: Did you followed documentation and added handling in the `Main` https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.ExecFunction#:~:text=you%20need%20to%20add%20a%20hook%20in%20the%20main%20function%3A ?

Comment: Hello @Serg. Sorry, but I had read documentation about this library in the other place and there wasn't this information there. I have just read that, but I don't know where there is placed the `Main()` in the MAUI. Maybe it is placed in some temporary internal file that is deleted when the solution is cleared, and in addition this file is different for different platforms. What about this?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/main-thread?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: @jdweng: hello! Interesting but, unfortunately, this is not what I was looking for. Did you read previous comments? I meant the `Main()` method, not the main thread.

Comment: Isn't MainCodeThred Main?  Do you see : "void MyMainThreadCode()"

Comment: @jdweng: no, I didn't. Maybe it is named in some other way, or is in the temporary internal file.

Comment: This may also help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/app-actions?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android

Comment: @jdweng: I have followed that instructions. But how to launch the app using the valid app action?

Comment: Did you modify the MainPage XAML? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/tutorials/notes-app/?view=net-maui-7.0&tutorial-step=2

Comment: I have read by diagonal, but haven't found the useful information there. Can you point to the certain words of that page or specify how to launch the certain method and NOT to show the extra content page when running under some app action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now launched the test function in that way. Maybe I did this through the anus, but here are the steps I did (for somebody who has similar problem):

1. Add the following lines into the `MauiProgram.cs` (new lines are marked with the `//Start` and `//End`):

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts => fonts
                .AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular")
                .AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold"))
            .ConfigureEssentials(essentials => essentials //Start
                .AddAppAction("main", "MainProgram", icon: "app_info_action_icon")
                .AddAppAction("secondary", "The second process has been launched!")
                .OnAppAction(App.HandleAppActions)); //End
#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

2. Add the following lines to `Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs`:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
 //Do not forget to add the following attribute!
[IntentFilter(new[] { Platform.Intent.ActionAppAction }, Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault })]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Platform.OnResume(this);
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Android.Content.Intent? intent) //Start
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        Platform.OnNewIntent(intent);
    } //End
}
```

3. To the `App.xaml.cs`, inside the class `App`:

```
    public static void HandleAppActions(AppAction appAction) => Current?.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
    {
        if (appAction.Id == "secondary")
        {
            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            if (args.Length >= 1)
                ExecFunction.Program.Main(args[1..]);
            return;
        }
        else if (Current.MainPage != null)
        {
            await Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
            await Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        }
    });
```

4. To the `MainPage.xaml.cs`, in the constructor **BEFORE** the `InitializeComponent()` line:

```
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args.Length >= 1 && ExecFunction.IsExecFunctionCommand(args = args[1..]))
        {
            ExecFunction.Program.Main(args);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

When doing the last step, I have thought that one had been able to avoid the first three ones. **If somebody has this problem, at first try the last step and only then the others.**

I have mentioned that I had launched the test function. It means that the function I really need still doesn't work, but for the other reasons that don't relate to this question's subject and would form the next my question.

EDIT: I have already launched the main function, too. Thanks to this forum, the program is working now. On the Russian forums, I used to receive mainly trolling. Let's see what will be here furthermore!